# What is the advantage of ChannelFactory use in WCF

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

few people add service reference and call the service and few people call service without service reference rather they create proxy at their end dynamically by ChannelFactory and call the service.

many people said often there is advantage of using ChannelFactory but i got any write up for the advantages of ChannelFactory. so if anyone know all the advantage of using ChannelFactory then please share with me. thanks

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

     var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
     var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://url:port"));
     factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

     var myService = factory.CreateChannel();

     myService.ServiceMethod();
```

Comment: In my case, this was better because I created a plugin for an application. I did not want the user to have to add all the bindings and information to the base web.config file so I created this channel factory so the end user didn't have to do anything to get my plugin to work.

Comment: The generic ChannelFactory<TChannel> class is used in advanced scenarios that require the creation of a channel factory that can be used to create more than one channel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @sjramsay : what u try to say not clear to me. when we create proxy using channel factory then also we need to mention binding etc in config file or in code. so please tell me what u try to say ? it will be very helpful if u come with a sample code where u will use channel factory just to show how u handle all the things. thanks